# Spring Cloud and RabbitMQ: how change the queue to auto-delete = false?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm using a Spring Cloud [example](https://github.com/ignacioSuay/spring-stream) with RabbitMQ.

After starting a docker with RabbitMQ:

```
sudo docker run -t -i --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

I executed the example of Publisher and Subscriber applications to watch the behavior of the messages.

One thing that I noted looking in the admin panel (http://localhost:15672) is that the Queue, created when the Subscriber is started, is configured to `auto-delete: true`. So, when there is no Subscriber running the Queue is not created and every message sent by Publisher is **discarded**. This is not what I expected to be the default configuration!

So, I would like to change the created Queue to `auto-delete: false`, because in this way the messages are not lost and when some subscriber start it will be able to consume the queued messages (right?). How I can do that on Spring?

As I said, all code that I'm using is available in this [example](https://github.com/ignacioSuay/spring-stream). The only change that I did was update the version of Spring Boot to 1.5.9.RELEASE.

Comment: Did you find a solutions to this ever?

Comment: @idipous I didn't test it, but I found a possible solution. I will share on the anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Spring Cloud Stream, [the option](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-stream-docs/Brooklyn.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties) to make the queue durable is `durableSubscription`:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.durableSubscription = true
```

As explained [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/54):

> depending on your needs, if you set it as an anonymous
>   consumer (no consumer group) then the queue will be automatically
>   deleted. This wouldn't work if you require multiple competing
>   consumers. If you do need a consumer group then you can use the
>   durableSubscription setting

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found working is this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<inputChanneName>.group=GROUP_NAME
```